# Strange Error: Beans not created, "Can not configure endpoints"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

So, thiss error appears in one of my team-members IntelliJ.

Anyone faced this or similar problem before?

Same code runs with no problems on my pc on intelliJ with same settings and 2 others with mac, also tried installing on another pc and no problem.

It's a big project, so you would need to ask for any code that would be helpfull. 
But still, the code should be ok because of running on several other machines.

- We checked javaversion in project settings, he got 8.241 and me 8.211. Trying the 8.211 didn't help.
- We checked java path in windows env variables, seems ok.
- We tried reinstall IntelliJ.
- We tried remove git repo, then new clone from bitBucket.
- We tried maven refresh/update
- We tried removing the .m2 folder
- We tried another computer (this one had same login though as the team-members pc that wont work)
- We checked env.variables in project
- We checked pom.xml

Everything seems ok, but application won't run.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-23 16:45:31.820  INFO 12592 --- [           main] se.companyName.appName.appNameApplication      : Starting appNameApplication on computer with PID 12592 (C:\git-repos\appName-api\target\classes started by myUserName in C:\git-repos\appName-api)
2020-03-23 16:45:31.858 DEBUG 12592 --- [           main] se.companyName.appName.appNameApplication      : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.7.RELEASE
2020-03-23 16:45:31.860  INFO 12592 --- [           main] se.companyName.appName.appNameApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-23 16:45:34.317  INFO 12592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-23 16:45:34.600  INFO 12592 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 257ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2020-03-23 16:45:35.751  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$349c9192] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:35.867  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd4a59cc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:35.892  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:35.897  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@378f002a' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:35.906  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f21efc7e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:35.915  INFO 12592 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-23 16:45:36.643  INFO 12592 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-23 16:45:36.699  INFO 12592 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-23 16:45:36.700  INFO 12592 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2020-03-23 16:45:37.229  INFO 12592 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-23 16:45:37.356 DEBUG 12592 --- [           main] s.h.a.security.filter.UserStatusFilter   : Filter 'userStatusFilter' configured for use
2020-03-23 16:45:37.913  INFO 12592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-23 16:45:38.818  INFO 12592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-23 16:45:42.256  INFO 12592 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-23 16:45:43.980  WARN 12592 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
2020-03-23 16:45:44.003  INFO 12592 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-23 16:45:44.008  INFO 12592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-23 16:45:44.026  INFO 12592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-03-23 16:45:44.029  INFO 12592 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-23 16:45:44.056  INFO 12592 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-23 16:45:44.093 ERROR 12592 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at se.companyName.appName.appNameApplication.main(appNameApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot configure enpdoints
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessTokenConverter' defined in class path resource [se/companyName/appName/security/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'accessTokenConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 18
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c09734a8.accessTokenConverter(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.configure(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.init(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'accessTokenConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 18
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 18
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaKeyHelper.parseKeyPair(RsaKeyHelper.java:56) ~[spring-security-jwt-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaSigner.loadPrivateKey(RsaSigner.java:77) ~[spring-security-jwt-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaSigner.<init>(RsaSigner.java:48) ~[spring-security-jwt-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(JwtAccessTokenConverter.java:177) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.accessTokenConverter(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:87) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c09734a8.CGLIB$accessTokenConverter$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c09734a8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$616eb46b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at se.companyName.appName.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c09734a8.accessTokenConverter(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 18
at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]
```

It looks like that the Self signed certificate or the PEM file is NOT present as expected in your setup. Checkout those files once, PEM file should not be encrypted.

Use the same SSL engine which was used to create those.